# JQuery find nested element in cloned object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to jquery and can't figure out why it isn't able to find nested span element.
My HTML is as follow:

```html
        <template id="repository_template">
          <section>
            <div>
              <div class="column">
                <img src="imgs/eyes.gif" alt="" width="20%">
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <span id="title" class="title"></span><br>
                <span id="description" class="subtitle"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </template>

        <div id="main">

        </div>
```

And, I'm trying to find `title` and `description` but it results in undefined.
What I've tried:

```js
// approach one

let appOne = $('#repository_template').clone();
let appOneTitle = appOne.find('#title');
console.log(appOneTitle.html());

// approach two
let $appTwo = $('#repository_template').clone();
let $appTwoTitle = $($appTwo).find('#title');
console.log($($appTwoTitle).html());

// approach three
let appThree = $('#repository_template').clone();
appThreeTitle = appThree.find('span');
console.log(appThreeTitle.html());
```

What I want to accomplish:

```js
let repoTemplate = $('#repository_template').clone();
repoTemplate.find('#title').text('Hello');
repoTemplate.find('#description').text('World!');

$('#main').append(repoTemplate.html());
```

Comment: A `<template>` is not like normal elements. It is a Web Component and has it's own API

Comment: Omg thank you! I overlooked that one. You are a sanity saver!